# Force Type Checking on Unions

Tags: python, types

I have a decorator that tests runs type check based on what is handed to the signature of a method. My limitation is that the isinstance check cannot handle Subscripted generics. Example being an error along these lines "TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks"

Any guidance on how to handle for instances where I would want to accept dynamic types outside of calling to Any

```
import functools
from typing import Any, Callable, List



def type_check(*args1, is_class_method=False):
    """
    Used for runtime type checking
    """

    def decorator(func: Callable):
        """
        functools.wraps maintains the integrity of the og func name
        """

        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args2, **keywords):
            args = args2[1:] if is_class_method else args2
            for (arg2, arg1) in zip(args, args1):
                if not isinstance(arg2, arg1):
                    raise TypeError(f"expected type: {arg1}, actual type: {type(arg2)}")
            return func(*args2, **keywords)

        return wrapper

    return decorator

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, a: Union[str, None] = None):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def a(self) -> Union[str, None]:
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    @type_check(Union[str,None], is_class_method=True)
    def a(self, value: Union[None, str]) -> None:
        self._a = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = TestClass()
```

Comment: Generics aren't true types. You cannot test using something like `isinstance`, you have to actually inspect the container itself. So if you have a union, say, `Union[str, None]`. Then you have to check `isinstance(x, (str, type(None))`

Comment: That certainly helps. I guess what I don't know how to do is how would I unpack that?